# XML Deserialization error: xxxxx was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I know there are several posts out there with this topic, but I can't seem to figure out what is the problem here. I have serialized and deserialized xml several times, and never had this error.

**The exception message is:**

> There is an error in XML document (1, 2).

**With InnerException:**

`<InvoiceChangeRequest xmlns=''> was not expected.`

**XML file I want to deserialize:**

```
<ns1:InvoiceChangeRequest xmlns:ns1="http://kmd.dk/fie/external_invoiceDistribution">
    <CONTROL_FIELDS>
        <STRUCTURID>0000000001</STRUCTURID>
        <OPERA>GET</OPERA>
        <WIID>000050371220</WIID>
    </CONTROL_FIELDS>
    <HEADER_IN>
        <MANDT>751</MANDT>
        <BELNR>1234567890</BELNR>
    </HEADER_IN>
    <ITEMS>
        <ITEM_FIELDS_IN>
            <BUZEI>001</BUZEI>
            <BUKRS>0020</BUKRS>
        </ITEM_FIELDS_IN>
    </ITEMS>
</ns1:InvoiceChangeRequest>
```

**Class I'm trying to deserialize to:**

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://kmd.dk/fie/external_invoiceDistribution", IsNullable = false)]
public class InvoiceChangeRequest
{
    [XmlElement("CONTROL_FIELDS")] public ControlFields Styrefelter;
    [XmlElement("HEADER_IN")] public HeaderIn HeaderfelterInd;
    [XmlElement("ITEMS")] public Items Linjer;
}

public class HeaderIn
{
    [XmlElement("MANDT")] public string Kommunenummer;
    [XmlElement("BELNR")] public string RegnskabsbilagsNummer;
}

public class Items
{
    [XmlElement("ITEM_FIELDS_IN")] public Itemfield[] ItemfelterInd;
}

public class Itemfield
{
    [XmlElement("BUZEI")] public string Linjenummer;
    [XmlElement("BUKRS")] public string Firmakode;
}
```

**Deserialization code:**

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InvoiceChangeRequest));
var request = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(output)) as InvoiceChangeRequest;
```

Comment: The XML is not valid.  XML can only have one root tag and you have multiple tags at root level.  The first line is not a valid tag sine there isn't a closing tag ns1:InvoiceChangeRequest.  Also you are missing on the first line the identification line start with <xml.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XML file your root element is the namespace `http://kmd.dk/fie/external_invoiceDistribution` with prefix `ns1`.

The element `<CONTROL_FIELDS>` isn't because it isn't prefixed. Your serialization class doesn't take this into account though. That means that it expects that `<CONTROL_FIELDS>` and the other elements are ALSO in the `ns1` namespace.

To get the serializer parse the elements correctly add the `Namespace` to the elements, setting it to an empty string:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://kmd.dk/fie/external_invoiceDistribution", IsNullable = false)]
public class InvoiceChangeRequest
{
    [XmlElement("CONTROL_FIELDS", Namespace = "")]
    public ControlFields Styrefelter { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("HEADER_IN", Namespace = "")]
    public HeaderIn HeaderfelterInd { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("ITEMS", Namespace = "")]
    public Items Linjer { get; set; }
}
```

This will de-serialize the given XML as intended.

In case of de-serialization issues I often create the classes in memory and then serialize that so I can inspect the resulting XML. That often gives clues on what is missing or being added compared to the input document:

```
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(ms, new InvoiceChangeRequest {
            Styrefelter = new ControlFields {  Opera="test"}
        });
        var s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

And then inspect `s` for differences.

Comment: Actually. The problem was out of scope - because I was unaware of a RemoveNamespace method before the deserializer. But off course, when the namespace was resolved, it worked. So your answer actually helped me on the way...

Comment: And if you look at the inner exception, it should have led me to the conclusion that the namespace actually was removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace 'ns1:' with string.Empty.

Below classes should serialize.

```
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("BUZEI")]
    public string Buzei { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("BUKRS")]
    public string Bukrs { get; set; }
}

public class Header
{
    [XmlElement("MANDT")]
    public string Mandt { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("BELNR")]
    public string Belnr { get; set; } 
}

public class ControlFields
{
    [XmlElement("STRUCTURID")]
    public string StructuredId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("OPERA")]
    public string Opera { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("WIID")]
    public string Wild { get; set; } 
}

public class InvoiceChangeRequest
{
    [XmlElement("CONTROL_FIELDS")]
    public ControlFields ControlFields { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("HEADER_IN")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("ITEMS")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ITEM_FIELDS_IN")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```